# How to write a sceneKit shader modifier for a dissolve in effect

Tags: ios, swift, shader, scenekit, metal

I'd like to build a dissolve in effect for a Scenekit game. I've been looking into shader modifiers since they seem to be the most light weight and haven't had any luck in replicating this effect:

[image: Dissolve shader effect]

Is it possible to use shader modifiers to create this effect? 
How would you go about implementing one?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can get pretty close to the intended effect with a fragment shader modifier. The basic approach is as follows:

- Sample from a noise texture
- If the noise sample is below a certain threshold (which I call "revealage"), discard it, making it fully transparent
- Otherwise, if the fragment is close to the edge, replace its color with your preferred edge color (or gradient)
- Apply bloom to make the edges glow

Here's the shader modifier code for doing this:

```
#pragma arguments

float revealage;
texture2d<float, access::sample> noiseTexture;

#pragma transparent
#pragma body

const float edgeWidth = 0.02;
const float edgeBrightness = 2;
const float3 innerColor = float3(0.4, 0.8, 1);
const float3 outerColor = float3(0, 0.5, 1);
const float noiseScale = 3;

constexpr sampler noiseSampler(filter::linear, address::repeat);
float2 noiseCoords = noiseScale * _surface.ambientTexcoord;
float noiseValue = noiseTexture.sample(noiseSampler, noiseCoords).r;

if (noiseValue > revealage) {
    discard_fragment();
}

float edgeDist = revealage - noiseValue;
if (edgeDist < edgeWidth) {
    float t = edgeDist / edgeWidth;
    float3 edgeColor = edgeBrightness * mix(outerColor, innerColor, t);
    _output.color.rgb = edgeColor;
}
```

Notice that the revealage parameter is exposed as a material parameter, since you might want to animate it. There are other internal constants, such as edge width and noise scale that can be fine-tuned to get the desired effect with your content.

Different noise textures produce different dissolve effects, so you can experiment with that as well. I just used this multioctave value noise image:

[image: Value noise image used as dissolve texture]

Load the image as a `UIImage` or `NSImage` and set it on the material property that gets exposed as `noiseTexture`:

```
material.setValue(SCNMaterialProperty(contents: noiseImage), forKey: "noiseTexture")
```

You'll need to add bloom as a post-process to get that glowy, e-wire effect. In SceneKit, this is as simple as enabling the HDR pipeline and setting some parameters:

```
let camera = SCNCamera()
camera.wantsHDR = true
camera.bloomThreshold = 0.8
camera.bloomIntensity = 2
camera.bloomBlurRadius = 16.0
camera.wantsExposureAdaptation = false
```

All of the numeric parameters will potentially need to be tuned to your content.

To keep things tidy, I prefer to keep shader modifiers in their own text files (I named mine "dissolve.fragment.txt").  Here's how to load some modifier code and attach it to a material.

```
let modifierURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "dissolve.fragment", withExtension: "txt")!
let modifierString = try! String(contentsOf: modifierURL)
material.shaderModifiers = [
    SCNShaderModifierEntryPoint.fragment : modifierString
]
```

And finally, to animate the effect, you can use a `CABasicAnimation` wrapped with a `SCNAnimation`:

```
let revealAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "revealage")
revealAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .linear)
revealAnimation.duration = 2.5
revealAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
revealAnimation.toValue = 1.0
let scnRevealAnimation = SCNAnimation(caAnimation: revealAnimation)
material.addAnimation(scnRevealAnimation, forKey: "Reveal")
```

[image: Et voila!]

Comment: Warren this is great. The high level overview of whats going on and then the detailed implementation is really really helpful. It makes a lot of sense when you break it down and using CABasicAnimation wrapped with SCNAnimation is clutch.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I think there a missing line regarding the animation code above. Make sure to add revealAnimation.autoreverses = true . It will autoreverse the animation and your animation will work like above.

Comment: Yes, to create the figure above, I used an autoreversing animation with an infinite repeatCount/repeatDuration. Neither is essential to demonstrating the effect, so I omitted them in the code.

Comment: First of all... this is [redacted]ing awesome!!  Seriously... not just a really great effect, but a really well-done answer too!  Voted up!  Question though... how do you detect the edge? Am I understanding that to be 'You're near the threshold between hidden and revealed, ergo it's an edge?'

Comment: When I tried this code, it could't find the revealage keyPath even though shader code has this revealage parameter. What could be the problem? 
I set the plane material in this way.

let material = SCNMaterial()
      material.setValue(SCNMaterialProperty(contents: noiseImage), forKey: "noiseTexture")
      plane.materials = [material]

Got this error:
 [SceneKit] Error: _C3DModelPathResolverRegistryResolvePathWithClassName unknown path (
    revealage
)