# How do you get Xcode to use syntax editing and code completion on Metal Shader Modifiers?

Tags: xcode, shader, embedded-resource, metal, fragment-shader

Beginning my adventure down the path of learning all about both Metal and shaders.  Currently I'm using [this example from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54567467/168179) to experiment with.

As you can see, he's storing his shader in a separate `.txt` file.  While I like the idea of the shader being a resource, I don't like that because it's text, I lose all syntax highlighting, code completion, etc.

I attempted to change the extension to `.metal` and Xcode did now recognize it as such with the color-coding, but now I can't build the app with Xcode saying there are tons of errors with it which clearly isn't correct as it works just fine as `.txt`.  To prove that, I simply changed it back again to being `.txt` and everything starts working as it was before, including with no highlighting or code completion.

Note: I also tried leaving it as text, but changing the type in the inspector to 'metal' but that didn't work either.

I keep hearing such great things about the metal debugger, but I can't even figure out how to get the metal *editor* working!  Help!

So... how can I include my shaders as separate `.metal` files (or comparable) and still be able to edit/run with it, both literally and figuratively?

Comment: Same issue in 2021

Answer (score 0):

In the example that you provided, @warrenm used `shaderModifiers`**:**

> A shader modifier is a snippet of source code in the Metal shader
> language or OpenGL Shader Language (GLSL) that SceneKit injects into
> its own shader programs at a defined entry point.

**.metal** - is a complete Vertex/Fragment/Compute implementation, which is not what `shaderModifiers` are.

Instead, you can create an [SCNProgram](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnprogram):
A complete Metal or OpenGL shader program that replaces SceneKit's rendering of a geometry or material.

Comment: You are correct. It's a shader modifier.  But that doesn't address what I'm trying to do, which is to get any kind of more-than-just-plain-text editing of those resources.  Do you have any suggestions there?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manually set the file type in the File Inspector:

[image]

Comment: Apologies. I thought I had put in my original question that I had already tried that but it didn't work.  I just edited the question to add that missing information in there.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you don't, not in the way you expect to, sorry.

The problem that you have stems not from Metal, but from the way SceneKit  allows to use Metal in a SceneKit application. Apple simply didn't put an effort into making this way IDE-worthy. Here's why.

First, I'm afraid you have some misconceptions about how all these things work, so let's clear things up. The text files you are editing are not "Metal shader modifiers" - it's not me being pedantic, we better clear this up from the beginning - they are rather SceneKit shader modifiers, one of three mutually incompatible ways of customizing the SceneKit rendering pipeline.

Metal is a rendering API, the lowest level you can draw graphics on screen without resorting to soldering. On the top of it, you have SceneKit. SceneKit is a game engine of sorts. It manages your "game loop", provides physics/hit testing capabilities, and manages rendering.

So, to render things, SceneKit internally sends commands to Metal. What it exactly tells Metal depends on how the scene is set up. Things on the scene can be customized in a variety of ways, but the problem is that they are all pre-defined. So, you can tell SceneKit "this material should have this texture", or "this light should have this strength", but when you go outside of these pre-defined settings - for example, when you want to say "this light should be rectangular, not a round spot" you have to write your own shader.

The industry standard for customizing shaders is visual programming. Dragging nodes around is a fun and interactive way for both artists and programmers. But SceneKit has no such thing. Instead, it basically allows you to hack into what SceneKit will send to Metal, and not in one, but in three possible ways. Shader modifiers are one of these ways, and it's the most "hacky": in the existing Metal shader that SceneKit developers made for their uncustomized rendering (*that SceneKit users don't even have the source code of,* they should just know it exists - however, some good people recovered it and posted on Github [here](https://gist.github.com/warrenm/794e459e429daa8c75b5f17c000600cf)), four "contact points" are defined, and in them, you can add your own statements into the shader's source code - your shader modifiers. SceneKit will add the shader modifier text to the shader source and re-compile the shader on the fly.

So now you can probably understand why Xcode complains: **shader modifiers are not valid Metal programs,** it's just bits that are to be inserted into the SceneKit's shader. (Xcode actually treats everything .metal that you put into the project as real source code - it compiles it with the special Metal compiler and links it together with your app's binary.) And Xcode has no special rules for treating SceneKit-specific stuff.

With all that said, I'd want to give you one more piece of advice:

Do NOT use SceneKit. SceneKit is an old, poorly documented and supported technology. Game engines are hard. Creating a modern general-purpose game engine is a task for decades of work of lots of people. Apple cannot create an adequate game engine without concentrating their efforts on doing that, and nobody should expect Apple to. The worth of knowledge and skills you acquire with learning SceneKit quickly diminishes over time because from the looks of it, SceneKit is going to be sunset by yet another Apple-unique thing called RealityKit that has all-new API, concepts, everything, not to mention that that worth was low from the beginning, because a) as I said, SceneKit is not good, and b) by using SceneKit, you are cutting yourself off from the Android and Windows markets. If you are interested in making games (or other 3D interactive applications), I strongly advise you to stick to the game industry flagships - Unity and Unreal engines. Take any game from the App Store's top 100, and I can guarantee you it doesn't use SceneKit, because that thing is not fit for anything complex.

However, if you want to learn strictly Metal, this is a much more promising endeavour (mostly because the cutting edge rendering API that everybody outside of the Apple world uses, "Vulkan", has similar concepts). This collection of official Apple's tutorials https://developer.apple.com/metal/sample-code/ seems like a great start. When making a bare Metal application, you will have access to auto-completion, because your .metal files will contain valid Metal programs.