# How do you specify a Metal texture format that's compatible with the iOS Simulator from an on-disk file?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, textures, metal, image-formats

Working with [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54567467/168179) here as a starting point, I'm trying to do something similar.  Pulling the `.jpg` texture from that post, my code runs just fine on a real device, but but fails in the simulator.  The reason appears to be because of the image format.

As mentioned in [Apple's documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/developing_metal_apps_that_run_in_simulator), you can't use format `MTLPixelFormat.r8Unorm_srgb` which is I believe what that texture is encoded in, based on the following error:

```
failed assertion `pixelFormat (11) is not a valid MTLPixelFormat.'
```

Trying to figure out how to change the format, but no idea how to go about it.  I don't know if it can be loaded into a particular color space at creation time, or if I have to do something specific in Photoshop, possibly even changing the file type altogether, but even there, I can't see how to turn off color profiles, just change them to something else.

So does anyone have any information on how one can create/load a texture that's also compatible with the simulator?

### Update

Per someone asking, here's how I am setting the texture.

```
let noiseImage = UIImage(resourceName: "Noise", extension: "jpg")!
myMaterial.setValue(SCNMaterialProperty(contents: noiseImage), forKey: "noiseTexture")
```

Here's the convenience initializer the above uses...

```
extension UIImage {

    convenience init?(resourceName:String, extension:String? = nil, bundle:Bundle? = nil) {

        let bundle = bundle ?? Bundle.main

        guard let resourceFileName = bundle.path(forResource: resourceName, ofType: `extension`) else {
            return nil
        }

        self.init(contentsOfFile: resourceFileName)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us exactly how you're creating the texture?

Comment: See the update.  Pretty sure it has nothing to do with the code as again, it runs fine on the simulator.  I think it's the jpg isn't in a format that works with the simulator.

Comment: It's not possible for a JPEG file to be in a "format" that isn't compatible with the Simulator. This has to do with how the texture is created and loaded, and in this instance, it appears to be a bug in SceneKit.

Comment: Not following how you're saying this is a bug if the image is apparently in `MTLPixelFormat.r8Unorm_srgb` format and the docs specifically say that format isn't supported in the simulator.  I have since converted it to a PNG with the color space 'Apple RGB' in Photoshop and the exact code now works in the simulator too, confirming it was a color format issue.  Still, I want to also try your code below as I prefer using Metal directly over UIKit for things like this.

Comment: A JPEG (or PNG) image doesn't explicitly contain an indication of which Metal pixel format its contents should be loaded into. Perhaps it contains a color profile that causes an internal texture loader (like the one in SceneKit) to _prefer_ a particular pixel format, at which point the loader's choice to pick a pixel format that isn't supported becomes a bug. Anyway, I'm happy for you that re-encoding the image appears to work.

Comment: I think it's the color profile issue.  BUT... the same file does work with your code, so now there are two solutions.  That said, I'm marking yours as the answer.  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in SceneKit, which isn't accounting for the fact that certain pixel formats aren't supported on the iOS Simulator. You can work around it by manually creating a Metal texture with MetalKit instead:

```
let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: scnView.device!)

let noiseImage = UIImage(resourceName: "Noise", extension: "jpg")?.cgImage
let texture = try! textureLoader.newTexture(cgImage: noiseImage!, options: [:])
myMaterial.setValue(SCNMaterialProperty(contents: texture), forKey: "noiseTexture")
```